# Unbend object bent with simple deform modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

Basically, if I bend a subdivided plane on the Z axis 180 degrees with the Simple Deform modifier and I've applied the modifier, is there any way to undo that bend? I have a mesh that looks like A, is there any way to deform it into mesh B?

I've been trying to achieve that with another Simple Deform Modifier, playing with the origin, the angle and so on, but I've been completely unsuccessful in getting back to the original shape.

[image]

Comment: First though, playing with the modifier angle? Or do you really want to keep it and add something else to obtain the B shape?

Comment: @lemon I had a very complex mesh that was a curtain that I spent quite a while texturing and modeling. I accidentally applied a Simple Deform modifier on it. I want to revert it back to how it was before applying the modifier, but I no longer have that save.

Comment: ok... did not mentioned it has been applied...

Comment: I was able to bend it back with another Simple Deform modifier, playing with the angle and finally setting it to -112 degrees, but it's still a bit curved, like this: https://i.imgur.com/ukgBj8N.png

It's what I meant by playing with angles.

Comment: Unfortunately, the inverse of a _Bend_ is not another _Bend_.  Check out [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/185128/35559) ..

Comment: @VitoriaBarros recommend edit any extra detail into question.  Unfolding flat "A" would be an easy script, however would say "A" is far from a complex mesh.

Comment: @RobinBetts select face loop in order, pop face at  one end  rotate others about edge (by face normals rot diff // aka edge angle) repeat till at other end.

Comment: @batFINGER Got you. Good for flat originals.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this way:

- Let's say you have object A (your half cylinder). Create a plane (object B), give it a *Simple Deform/Bend* modifier, bend it 180°:

[image]

[image]

- Overlap the 2 objects (scale object B if necessary), give to object A a *Surface Deform* modifier with object B as *Target*, click on *Bind*:

[image]

- Bring back object B to  an angle of 0°, object A will follow:

[image]

Comment: that's a very nice approximation! i was wondering if there is a more perfect method?

Comment: @Harry McKenzie Robin Betts had a cleaner method but I can't tell you where to find it   :(  maybe he could tell

Comment: oh i found it, there was a link in the comments of question. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185087/transform-cylinder-to-flat-plane-cylinder-maze-map/185128#185128

Comment: Oh OK that's it  ;)  ..............