# How to decurve or straighten a mesh?

Tags: modeling, armature, geometry

Well I have a curved mesh that I want it to be straight.

I wanted to know what is the best and fastest way to straighten this mesh.

The mesh is already bent and I now use the armature and some sculpting to make it straight , is there any plugin or node group that can help me make these ornamentals with curves?

[image]

[image]

here is the other one
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185087/transform-cylinder-to-flat-plane-cylinder-maze-map/ or this one https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194472/unbend-object-bent-with-simple-deform-modifier

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Nope ! , i uploaded the blend file , i want something to reverse the curve modifier

Comment: Curving a geometry is destructive in a sense (I don't mean procedural vs destructive workflow here), some information is lost, like with a blur. Philosophically speaking, some people argue the information is never lost (with a controversy regarding black holes) and so theoretically the original shape could be restored, maybe with some damage due to a limited float precision… However, reversing some processes is just impractical. What makes a night and day difference is the info about the modifier initially applied - having such data opens some reasonable, practical, reliable strategies.

Comment: I tried with a cruve that has 2 shapekeys, a flat shape and one that follows the leaf bend, in order to try a retro-curve operation, but no good success so far  :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your suggestion to use armature gives an excellent result, you should write your own answer, my test:

[image]

My try with lattice:

You could try with a *Lattice* modifier, make the lattice cage flat, subdivide it a bit on its length, then deform it to straighten the leaf:

[image]

Quick result (on the right the final goal):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot but this isn't exactly what i wanted , you see when the mesh is straight we can easily curve it with curve modifier not reverse , if i want to do such thing other parts of the mesh will be deformed so bad that i can't use it at all , i''ll upload blend file

Comment: So , i have added another one of my flowers there as you can see it is not possible to decurve it with lattice , although your method is good i appreciate your effort

Comment: @hamed.design this is the right answer, please can you mark it as answered with the green checkmark

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie no its not ! could you please review the question again , in this method we can't straighten the more curved objects

Comment: It seems impossible to do it properly, what is your situation exactly? If you had straighten versions, you should have kept them of course...

Comment: @moonboots dear my friend , in a very harsh circumstances like the second model if i'd force to do so , i use the armature with automatic weight and bending bones for all  as i said before , and if you change the answer maybe edit it a littlebit for documentation maybe someone else wanted to know the answer i will accept the answer for sure , otherwise maybe there is another way to do it who knows ?

Comment: So I've tested your idea and it works fine, I've edited my answer but you should write your own answer